# QgsProcessingException running JoinAttributesByLocation

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am trying to run the following code

```
import os
directory_in_str='/Users/name/Desktop/test/'
directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)
tre='?type=csv&quote=&escape=&trimFields=Yes&skipEmptyFields=Yes&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xyDms=yes&xField=lon&yField=lat&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=yes&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no'
start='file:///Users/name/Desktop/test/'
for file in os.listdir(directory):
     filename = os.fsdecode(file)
     if filename.endswith(".csv"): 
        path_to_csv=start+filename+tre
        processing.run("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", {'INPUT':path_to_csv,'JOIN':'/Users/name/Desktop/gis/NUTS_uppdelade/NUTS_ID_SE11.gpkg|layername=NUTS_ID_SE11','PREDICATE':[0,5],'JOIN_FIELDS':[],'METHOD':0,'DISCARD_NONMATCHING':True,'PREFIX':'','OUTPUT':'/Users/name/Desktop/gis/regn/vikter/NUTS_ID_SE111900Q1.gpkg'})
```

My intention is to get the script to run the join attributes by location for all files in folder test. However, it returns the following error:

```
exec(open('/var/folders/ks/1x_p2hz95jldm5xvpjfg0gmm0000gn/T/tmpdq2z8ia3.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 106, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 137, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Kan inte köra algoritm
Kunde inte läsa in källager för INPUT: file:///Users/name/Desktop/test/1900Q1.csv?type=csv&quote=&escape=&trimFields=Yes&skipEmptyFields=Yes&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xyDms=yes&xField=lon&yField=lat&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=yes&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no ej hittad
```

Meaning that the layer could not be found. I can't really get my head around why I get this error message since it works when replacing path_to_csv with a copy paste of the strings it is supposed to combine.

So I assume that I specify the path_to_csv wrong in some sort. Any advice?

Edit 1:
If relevant, this is the code I have been successful running:

```
processing.run("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", {'INPUT':'file:///Users/name/Desktop/test/1900Q1.csv?type=csv&quote=&escape=&trimFields=Yes&skipEmptyFields=Yes&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xyDms=yes&xField=lon&yField=lat&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=yes&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no','JOIN':'/Users/name/Desktop/gis/NUTS_uppdelade/NUTS_ID_SE11.gpkg|layername=NUTS_ID_SE11','PREDICATE':[0,5],'JOIN_FIELDS':[],'METHOD':0,'DISCARD_NONMATCHING':True,'PREFIX':'','OUTPUT':'/Users/name/Desktop/gis/regn/vikter/NUTS_ID_SE111900Q1.gpkg'})
```

Comment: Yes, it should be correct. I double checked looking at history, it indeed uses three ///.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not specify that it was a QgsVectorLayer.

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_csv, "temp", "delimitedtext")
```

```
processing.run("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", {'INPUT':vlayer,'JOIN':'/Users/name/Desktop/gis/NUTS_uppdelade/NUTS_ID_SE11.gpkg|layername=NUTS_ID_SE11','PREDICATE':[0,5],'JOIN_FIELDS':[],'METHOD':0,'DISCARD_NONMATCHING':True,'PREFIX':'','OUTPUT':'/Users/name/Desktop/gis/regn/vikter/NUTS_ID_SE111900Q1.gpkg'}
```

Now, it runs smoothly!